# Limit ratio test take derivative with respect to what?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose I define a sequence as follows: $a_n = a_{n-1} + n^2$.

Let's say I'd like to see if this sequence converges by performing the ratio test to see if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$.

Let's pretend that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is either $\frac{\infty}{\infty} or \frac{0}{0}$ (I realize it's not) and requires applying l'Hopital's Rule.

In this case, what would I take the derivative with respect to, $a_n$ or to $n$? So would the numerator become $\frac{\partial}{\partial a_n}=1$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial n}= 2n$?

Comment: You can't use the L'Hopital rule when it's **not** an indeterminate form.

Comment: What are you taking the limit of? $n \to \infty$ or $a_n \to \infty$? That should be a big clue

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say I'd like to see if this *sequence* converges by performing the ratio test to see if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$.

I assume you want to check the converges of the **series** $\sum a_n$ by applying the ratio test?

It would be the derivative with respect to $n$, the variable of $a_n = a(n)$.

> Suppose I define a sequence as follows: $a_n = a_{n-1} + n^2$.

Note that your example is a recursively defined sequence; it would be easier to work with an explicit formula to directly apply the ratio test.

In any case, if you have expressions for $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ and the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$$
would give an indeterminate form where l'Hôpital applies ($\tfrac{0}{0}$ or $\tfrac{\infty}{\infty}$), then you can proceed by taking the derivative with respect to $n$.

---

To compare: in the context of real functions where you have a similar indeterminate form for a limit of the form $\tfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, you don't take the derivative with respect to $f(x)$ (and/or $g(x)$), but with respect to (the variable) $x$!

Comment: Question: If my sequence were $b_n = 1 - cos(a_n)$ in which $a_n \to 0$. This would indeed be equal to 0. However, here, I seem to take the derivative with respect to $a_n$, so it would become $sin(a_n)$. That seems to suggest you take the derivative with respect to $a_n$, no?

Comment: You should clarify your example (perhaps in your initial question; provide the full example then); here you have another sequence ($a_n$) _within_ the sequence $b_n$...?